# Explode string into array with key and value

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I've a string like this:

```
$mystring = '{"1":"4","2":"2","3":"3"}';
```

I need to explode to something like this:

```
array(
  "1" => "4",
  "2" => "2",
  "3" => "3"
)
```

I use php 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$dd = json_decode($mystring, true);
var_export($dd);
```

Answer (score 1):

you "string" is very like json so maybe try [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the json decode function, your string looks like json. The second argument tells to make it as an array, not an object.

```
json_decode($mystring, true);
```