# create array with key and value from string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string:

```
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";
```

I want to create an array where the **first** item is the `key` and the **second** one the `value`.

It should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [test] => something
    [other] => things
    [data] => example
)
```

How can I do that? It's difficult to search for a solution because I don't know how to search this.

It's very similar to this: [Explode string into array with key and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381807/explode-string-into-array-with-key-and-value)

But I don't have a json array.

I tried something like that:

```
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";

$arr = explode(',', $content);

$counter = 1;
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $item) {
    if($counter % 2 == 0) {
        $result[$temp] = $item;
        unset($temp);
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $temp = $item;
        $counter++;
        continue;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

But it's a dirty solution. Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Are you sure that word count will be always in even no?

Comment: @ManishShukla Yes, it will be :)

Comment: Love it when comments: *Have you tried something?* gets completely ignored.

Comment: There are so many people writing at the moment. Please give me a bit time for answering^^. I tried to add a counter which checks if the counter value is even or odd.

Comment: @Vince ^^ Then add your attempt to your question and show your effort and work which you have done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = explode(',',$content);
$size = count($array);
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
    $result[$array[$i]] = $array[++$i];
```

Comment: Man this is a short solution :) Didn't know that `++$i` works. thank you!

Comment: @AhmedZiani Don't do: `$i<count($array)` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674485/create-array-with-key-and-value-from-string#comment47487258_29674832 So it's even worse what you do

Comment: @AhmedZiani Because you call `count()` in every iteration!

Comment: @AhmedZiani Because it's very bad practice and kills performance?!

Comment: @AhmedZiani *Yes* Then why did you do it this way? (Extract it from the loop?! Then you only call it once instead of like 200 times?!)

Comment: @AhmedZiani *Yes you are right !* And what now? Are you going to edit your answer or just leave it with this quality? (Also you may want to add an explanation for OP and further readers to understand what your code does)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";
$data = explode(",", $content);// Split the string into an array
$result = Array();
$size = count($data); // Calculate the size once for later use
if($size%2 == 0)// check if we have even number of items(we have pairs)
for($i = 0; $i<$size;$i=$i+2){// Use calculated size here, because value is evaluated on every iteration
$result[$data[$i]] = $data[$i+1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";
$firstArray = explode(',',$content);

print_r($firstArray);

$final = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($firstArray); $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
    {
        $final[$firstArray[$i]] = $firstArray[$i+1];
    }   
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could able to use the following:

```
$key_pair = array();
$arr = explode(',', $content);
$arr_length = count($arr);
if($arr_length%2 == 0)
{
   for($i = 0; $i < $arr_length; $i = $i+2)
   {
     $key_pair[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
   }
}
print_r($key_pair);
```

Comment: I think an explanation for OP and further readers would be helpful what your code does and why!

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";
$x = explode(',', $content);

$z = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($x); $i+=2){
    $res[$x[$i]] = $x[$i+1];
    $z=array_merge($z,$res);
}

print_r($z);
```

Comment: I think an explanation for OP and further readers would be helpful what your code does and why!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this example this is working file.

**Code:-**

```
    <?php
 $string = "test,something|other,things|data,example";
 $finalArray = array();

 $asArr = explode( '|', $string );
 foreach( $asArr as $val ){
 $tmp = explode( ',', $val );
 $finalArray[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];
 }
 echo "After Sorting".'<pre>';
 print_r( $finalArray );
 echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [test] => something
    [other] => things
    [data] => example
)
```

For your reference check this [Click Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fia7xX)

Hope this helps.

Comment: My string is very long so I can't just replace each second comma with a pipe. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "test,something,other,things,data,example";

$contentArray = explode(',',$content);
for($i=0; $i<count($contentArray); $i++){
    $contentResult[$contentArray[$i]] = $contentArray[++$i];
}
print_r( $contentResult);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [test] => something
    [other] => things
    [data] => example
)
```

1. $contentResult[$contentArray[1]] = $contentArray[2];
2. $contentResult[$contentArray[3]] = $contentArray[4];
3. $contentResult[$contentArray[5]] = $contentArray[6];

Comment: I think an explanation for OP and further readers would be helpful what your code does and why!